# Managing two different Azure resources under the same domain name with domain routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to deploy a React app with a simple content management function in Microsoft Azure.
When users access static content on the website, the app simply reads html code from a database, and display it.
Given that the html code itself is static, I need to host files like images as static resources in Azure blob storage. But since I already assigned my custom domain name to the app, I am not able to use the same domain name with blob storage.
How do I integrate blob storage in my app so that when the browser tries to access files hosting under the route i.e. "/assets", that it looks up the path name and file name in the corresponding folder in Azure blob storage?

For example, if the html code wants to access "/assets/img/1.jpg", it will get "/img/1.jpg" from my Azure Blob Storage folder?

Answer (score 1):

•   You can integrate azure blob storage in your react app by setting the resource name in ‘src/azure-storage-blob.ts’ as follows: -

‘const storageAccountName = process.env.storageresourcename || "fileuploaddemo";’
•   Generate a SAS token with the below parameters: -

Property    Value
Allowed services    Blob
Allowed resource types  Service, Container, Object
Allowed permissions Read, write, delete, list, add, create
Enable deletions of version Checked
Start and expiry date/time  Accept the start date/time and set the end date time 24 hours in the future. Your SAS token is only good for 24 hours.
HTTPS only  Selected
Preferred routing tier  Basic
Signing Key key1 selected

•   Set the SAS token in the ‘src/azure-storage-blob.ts’ as follows. Don’t add the ‘?’ in the SAS token value when adding the SAS token in the code.

// remove `?` if it is first character of token
const sasToken = process.env.storagesastoken || "SAS token";

•   Now, configure CORS to allow the resource to connect to the app with custom domain name and save it. Thus, you will be able to upload the images in the azure blob storage by opening the app URL in the browser locally.

•   Once the images are uploaded, they can be accessed and arranged through the storage explorer in a hierarchy and similarly the path of those images can be mapped to the Azure blob storage and accessed through a browser.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal

Thanking you,